# When I click a button the page does not refresh in React Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a page that when I click the shop button the URL is displayed on the url space but the page does not load onclick of the button

```
import React from "react";
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import './menu-item.styles.scss'

const MenuItem= ({title, imageUrl, size, history, linkUrl , match}) => (
    <div 
        className={`${size} menu-item`} 
        onClick = {() => history.push(`${match.url},${linkUrl}`)}>
        <div 
            className="background-image"
            style={{
            backgroundImage : `url(${imageUrl})`
            }}
        />
        <div className="content">
            <h1 className="title">{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
            <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
        </div>
    </div>
)

export default withRouter(MenuItem);
```

The page that is supposed to display is only shown when I refresh the page but when I click the button the url is displayed but not loaded.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

import HomePage from './pages/homepage/home.component';
import ShopPage from './pages/shop/shop.components';
import Header from './components/header/header.component';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
        <Route path='/shop' component={ShopPage}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You should use window.href = `${match.url},${linkUrl}` in  that case.

Comment: Why do you have a comma between `${match.url}` and `${linkUrl}` in `history.push`? Could you show an example of what the string within `history.push` might look like? Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems malformed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because you're navigating to the page you're already on. But are you sure that you want that at all? If the reason is that you want to show updated data on your page, then this is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

```
    <NavLink 
        className={`${size} menu-item`} 
        to={linkUrl}>
        <div 
            className="background-image"
            style={{
            backgroundImage : `url(${imageUrl})`
            }}
        />
        <div className="content">
            <h1 className="title">{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
            <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
        </div>
    </NavLink>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).